# NuxtJS component auto import stopped working out of nowhere

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have this project I'm writing in NuxtJS (without TypeScript) and I have a few custom components in components directory. It was working fine yesterday, but now, it suddenly says that the component wasn't registered correctly, this happens only with components that aren't in the root of `components` directory. What do I do?

This is the error:
[image]

This is my nuxt.config.js:
[image]

This is my components directory:
[image: This is my components directory]

As you can see, I already have some components there, I swear, they were working fine yesterday. What could be causing this?

What I've tried:
• Deleting .nuxt directory;
• Setting manually the components directory in the configuration file (as described in this link [from @nuxt/components lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxt/components)

Importing the component manually works fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I just deleted node_modules and now works fine.
I don't know what just happened. It must be one of that node related akwardness!